# Setting visibility prop of Modal to false hides other components in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a component structured like this:

```
<View>
  <Navigation/>
  <Title/>
  <FlatList/>
  <Modal/>
</View>
```

Each time I setState of visibility of the Modal to false, the Modal disappears as it should, but my `<Navigation/>` component disappears as well. It literally poofs out of sight without unmounting. I've replaced `<Navigation/>` with other types of Navigation components as well and it does the same thing. When I place multiple `<Navigations/>` onto the screen, each time I do `this.setState({modalVisible: false})` it hides one Navigation and then another when I setState to false again; popping them off the screen one at a time.

This Modal functionality worked without this bug before. I have changed other things in the application but the directive of the `modalVisible` state is too clear to get wrong. I pass it only to the `<Modal/>` for its `visible` prop and that's it, nowhere else.

Can someone provide a reason for why this might be happening please?!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the solution was to position the Modal above every other component as such:

```
<View>
  <Modal/>
  <Navigation/>
  <Title/>
  <FlatList/>
</View>
```

Doing this prevented the `<Navigation/>` from disappearing along with the `<Modal/>`. The reason behind this is still a mystery to me however. So if anyone has an explanation for this, please enlighten me or us. I find it hard to believe that this "fix" has not trumped others before.

P.S. Pun definitely intended.